# How do we use static map in template class, with every instantiation of template class the same map should be used

Tags: c++

I am using the following code snippet.
When i instantiate the TemplateClass twice (once with int and next with double), I happen to see same size in getKey. whereas map is static and the size should be 2 in second time.

```
template<typename T>
class TemplateClass
{
    private:
        static std::map<int, T> *mKey;
    public:
        TemplateClass()
        {
        }
        void insert(T value, int count)
        {
            (*TemplateClass<T>::mKey)[count]=value;
        }
        long getKey(){return mKey->size();}
};

template<typename T>
std::map<int,T> *TemplateClass<T>::mKey = new std::map<int,T>;
int main()
{
    TemplateClass<int> obj1;
    obj1.insert(10, 1);
    std::cout<<"Object 1 key is: "<<obj1.getKey()<<std::endl;
    TemplateClass<double> obj2;
    obj2.insert(222.1122, 2);
    std::cout<<"Object 1 key is: "<<obj2.getKey()<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Ahh lot of things, tried having parent class with static map.
Global static map.

Comment: Pointers to containers are seldom, if ever, needed. And here it's really not needed. Or if you come from a C# or Java environment, `new` isn't needed to create objects in C++.

Comment: `TemplateClass` is a *template* not a full class or type. `TemplateClass<int>` is a type. And `TemplateClass<double>` is a ***different*** class (and type). Therefore `TemplateClass<int>::mKey` is different from `TemplateClass<double>::mKey`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. Is there anyway I can have map as a shared object between both of them? I tried n number of things but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 4):

`TemplateClass<int>::mKey` and `TemplateClass<double>::mKey` are two different objects. They are each `static` in the sense that they are not associated to any instance of either type, but the two instantiations `TemplateClass<int>` and `TemplateClass<double>` of the class template `TemplateClass` are distinct class types and so all their members are also distinct.

For any distinct types `T` and `U`, the class types `TemplateClass<T>` and `TemplateClass<U>` are completely separate class types, that just happen to share a similar structure due to being instantiated from the same class template.

You could have (for the most part) just as well defined two non-templated classes `TemplateClassInt` and `TemplateClassDouble` with all mentions of `T` being replaced by `int` in the first one and `double` in the second one.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. Is there anyway I can have map as a shared object between both of them? I tried n number of things but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: @sarabjitkaur No, not directly. The two maps have different type (`std::map<int, int>` vs `std::map<int, double>`). If you are happy with having the same type for both, you can simply declare a global outside any class, otherwise you might be looking for something like `std::variant`. But most likely you are approaching your *actual* problem wrong here. What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: The ultimate goal here is to maintain instances of different types in map so we can retrieve them later corresponding to a unique key. One way I could think was to have void* kind of implementation if type is an issue here. But then that could be erroneous later.

Comment: @sarabjitkaur If that is really what you want and the number of potential types for the map is limited, then go with `std::map<int, std::variant<int, double, otherTypes>> `, which does however require extra work in using it. C++ is statically typed, so the type of every expression must be known at compile-time. Therefore using containers that could have elements of different types is a non-trivial task. Try figuring out whether this is really necessary for your design.

Comment: If all element types are classes derived from the same base, you might want to use `std::map<int, BaseType*>`, depending on the use case.

Comment: not on C++ 17 yet. but i guess map of function pointer should work. As in the end we have to use callback function from the key-value pair. :) shall update once it works! thanks a ton!